# Why can't I use gradient vector's magnitude as surface integral's area element?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I understand that when calculating the surface integral, we have to parametrize the surface by a 2-variables vector equation. Then, the cross product of the two velocity partial vectors would then become the area element. This cross product, at the same time, would be the candidate of normal vector.

However, I also know that the gradient vector would be perpendicular to its level set or level surface.

So I wonder could I use the magnitude of the gradient vector as the area element?

Comment: The zero level sets of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$ and $g(x,y,z)=10f(x,y,z)$ have the same area (since they are the same surface), but the magnitudes of the gradient vectors are very different.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! but is it fine to use gradient vector divided by its magnitude to be that unit normal vector? Just saying if there is really such case.

Comment: Yes, the gradient divided by its magnitude is the unit normal. However it does not give you an area element.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, you have got what I need! Much thanks!